# Can I use wildcards in appname when creating a rule

Tags: awesome-wm

Can I use "*" in application name. Something like:

```
{ rule = { name = "Appname*" },
```

Answer (score 1):

The code uses Lua's `string.match`, so the patterns that are explained at http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial can be used. For your case that should be `"Appname.*"`, if I'm reading this correctly.